# How do I get Emacs to auto-complete tags and brackets for me?

Tags: emacs

I've used Emacs for all my development for some time now, but only recently did I start developing HTML. I was wondering how I can configure Emacs to auto-complete tags for me. Also, I'd like for Emacs to auto-complete brackets for me in languages like Java and C.

I looked at the customization options, under Programming but there was no option for customizing for HTML or Java. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you try [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) for completion? and there is [autopair](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) to insert closing brackets.

Comment: yasnippet worked perfectly! I haven't tried autopair, but thanks for the tips!

Comment: Hey, I was just trying to set up yasnippet on my Mac, but there is no ~/.emacs file. I made a new file with that name, but I get an error when I start emacs. The error is that the file `yasnippet-bundle` could not be loaded. Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Another nice mode for emacs for HTML & other **web** related work is the aptly-named web-mode. You can learn about it here: [http://web-mode.org/](http://web-mode.org)